# Very Simple INNER JOIN inquiry

Tags: sql, hql, hive

Let's say I have the below table1

```
User |
1    |
2    |
3    |
4    |
```

And, I want to join it to the following table2

```
User | Color  
1    | Blue
1    | Yellow
1    | Yellow
5    | Red
5    | Green
```

If i want to get the following result set below, is the correct query:

SELECT a.User FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b on a.user=b.user

Desired Result:

```
User |
1    |
1    |
1    |
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?  It looks correct.

Comment: looks good... capitalize u in a.User=b.User

Comment: could similarly do: SELECT a.User From a,b Where a.User=b.User

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a WHERE statement if you want only 1's to show up.

```
SELECT a.User FROM table1 a 
INNER JOIN table2 b 
ON a.user=b.user 
WHERE a.User = 1;
```

The rest is correct though.

[Blog Post](http://imprintedstudios.com/isscriptcode/sql-inner-join-2/)